# Swipe Gesture with Two Fingers

Tags: xamarin.ios

I added the SwipeGesture to a View on my Page. If i make a Left Swipe the View switches to another Subview. Same if you do a right swipe.

The Problem is, that on one of my pages is a `UISlider` and if you change the value of this, the Swipe Gesture Triggers and Navigates to another Subview.

Is it possible to make a Swipe Gesture which triggers if you swipe with 2 Fingers?

Comment: I think users of your app are going to get confused if they have to do multi-finger swipes.  Is there a way tor rearrange your UI so it makes more sense?

Comment: 100% agreed with @Jonathan.Peppers. Try to avoid the `UISlider` or workaround/ignore it's gesture to switch views (instead of having a different swiping requirement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a swipe gesture with two fingers using the numberOfTouchesRequired property. I agree with @Jonathan.Peppers though that if you have conflicting gesture patterns it's bad UX practice to slightly differentiate them by incrementing the touch points.

I would also recommend using this abstraction for using gestures and modify it using some sort of type check for swipe: https://gist.github.com/1453770

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(UISwipeGestureRecognizer)) {
    ((UISwipeGestureRecognizer)fRecognizer).NumberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
}
```